# Fix data to show with scroll bar with morris graph

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, morris.js

I am using Morris Bar chart with php with data from mysql database

Now it is showing bar graph.

My question is:

There are about 100 rows in mysql database and they are increasing day by day.

My bar graph is displaying date wise data.

Can we fix number of days to display bargraph along with horizontal scroll bar to view previous data ?

Code I am using now is as follows :

```
<div id="graphdatewise"></div>

<script>
        $(function () {
            var graphdatewise = {
                      element: 'graphdatewise',
                      data: <?php echo json_encode($chartresult);?>,
                      xkey: 'cur_date',
                      ykeys: ['counter', 'counter_unique_visit'],
                      labels: ['PageViews', 'UniqueVisits'],
                      parseTime: true,
                      barColors: ['#F4FA58', '#00FFFF'],
                      xLabels: 'Date',                   
                      xLabelAngle: 70
                    }
                    bar1 = Morris.Bar(graphdatewise)
            });
    </script>
```

**Now with this code, bars get resized and whole data is displayed in graph. Instead of that can we show 10 days data in graph with horizontal scroll bar to access rest data ?**

Answer (score 0):

It is not possbile to make a x-scroll with Morris chart. But I suppose that if you limit the width of the parent  widder than the width of the chart, that should be ok. Something like:

```
<div id='parent' style='width: 100px;'>
    <div id='graphdatewise' style='width: 50px;'></div>
</div>
```